# Can't figure out why i'm Getting a 424 error when i use an IF/Then in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, object, if-statement

Part of a larger code, but I'm trying to fill out the blank spaces in a column that I can then delete later.

But if the column doesn't have blank spaces I need it to stop and move onto the next step instead.

I did this by having the code check column A, if Column A is blank than that means there are no blank cells in the column i'm checking.

However, whenever I ask this to do an If/Then statement to check if a particular nearby cell is blank it gives me a 424 error.

No idea what's causing this.

```
Range("D1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3) Is Blank Then
GoTo Continue1
Else
End If

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DELETEGREENELEPHANTS"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown

Continue1:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Is Blank` doesn't work. `Blank` is an undeclared object.

Use [`IsEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isempty-function):

```vb
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)) Then
```

I *highly* suggest you see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for how to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`.

Also the use of `GoTo` here is generally frowned upon; that's creating spaghetti code. Here's a simplified approach that doesn't use `GoTo`:

```vb
If Not Is Empty(ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3)) Then
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DELETEGREENELEPHANTS"
   ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Range("A1").Select
   Selection.End(xlDown).Select
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Range("A1").Select
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
   Selection.FillDown
End If
```

noting that everything inside the `If...End If` should be rewritten to avoid `Select` and `ActiveCell`.

Comment: I suppose I could nest the part that adds "DELETEGREENELEPHANTS" into the Else part of the If/Then statement, but i'd still need to put in the GoTo for it to do something when it's blank, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 1):

The code for checking is:

IsEmpty(CellValue) - it returns a Boolean.

https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/use-isempty-vba-to-check-if-cell-is-blank/